# Trigger breakpoint in Python unit test invoked from coverage in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, coverage.py

I am writing unit tests for my Python 3.6 module using the built in [unittest framework](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html). I am using [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/python) (VS Code) as my IDE. My tests are invoked using the Python [coverage tool](https://coverage.readthedocs.io/) thus

```bash
coverage run --include=preprocessing/load_data.py preprocessing/test_load_data.py 
coverage report --show-missing
```

I'm getting an error from one of my tests that I suspect is related to how the test environment is set up and so I would like to trigger a breakpoint in the test. If I was running the test directly from Python I could easily set up a configuration in VC Code's launch.json but I cannot see how to do that for code invoked indirectly by coverage. Here's my attempt:

```json
{
    "name": "Python: Use Coverage to Run Tests",
    "type": "python",
    "request": "launch",
    "module": "coverage",
    "args": [ 
        "run", "--include=preprocessing/load_data.py",
        "preprocessing/test_load_data.py"
    ],
    "console": "integratedTerminal"
}
```

This does run the program, but the breakpoint does not trigger.

I have also tried to [attach to a local script](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_attach-to-a-local-script) but adding

```python
ptvsd.enable_attach(address=('localhost', 5678), redirect_output=True)
ptvsd.wait_for_attach()
```

causes an error from the coverage tool:

```
sys.settrace() should not be used when the debugger is being used.  
Call Location:  
    File "C:\Anaconda\envs\talia36\lib\site-packages\coverage\collector.py", line 278, in _installation_trace  
    sys.settrace(None)
```

How might I configure Python debugging under VS Code so that my unit test is called from coverage and the breakpoint triggers?

Comment: Have you tried using Python's built-in function `breakpoint`? It drops you into a pdb as soon as the interpreter reaches that line. [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#breakpoint)

Comment: Both the debugger and coverage use the same mechanism to work, so it's possible one of them is wiping out the other.